# How can I use transfromControl with group?

Tags: angular, three.js

I am trying to select a group of object using transformControl in [Three.js](https://threejs.org/). I would like to rotate, scale and translate it.
I've seen many answers but most of them were incomplete or really complicated to implement. I'm creating an editor and would like kind of the same result as in [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/). also I'm using angular that shouldn't be a problem but just to let you know

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, I will sometimes create a temporary THREE.Group or THREE.Object3D,

then use the .attach() to attach each object to the temporary group/object.. Use the transformcontrols to manipulate that object, and when the manipulation is complete,
use scene.attach() to attach the objects back to the scene.

Comment: I just saw I could in fact transform a group with the tranformControl. Any code for your example. Also I'm not able to center the control any idea?

Comment: I don't have an isolated example, but I do remember setting up the Empty, to the average of all the selected objects positions, so that it is roughly in the middle of them.

Comment: what do you exactly call the Empyt?

Comment: say you have 3 meshes.. m1,m2,m3..
```
let empty = new THREE.Group()
empty.position.copy(m1.position).add(m2.position).add(m3.position).multiplyScalar(1 / 3)
empty.updateMatrixWorld()
empty.attach(m1)
empty.attach(m2)
empty.attach(m3)
```